# HTML Meta Description + &

Tags: html

which of the following should I use in the meta description tag:

```
 &
 &amp;
```

eg:

```
 <meta name="description" content="text text & text...">
 <meta name="description" content="text text &amp; text...">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should HTML encode the value, like every value that you put in an HTML attribute.

```
<meta name="description" content="text text &amp; text...">
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using "&" at all.  Google and most other search engines ignore symbols, so your best bet would be using the word "and."

Comment: It’s not quite that simple. When a search engine uses a meta description to construct an extract of page contents in search results, as they still do sometimes, they probably display the “&” character too, if it is part of the data.
Moreover, search engines sometimes pay attention to special character, as you can see by comparing the Google results for `&foo` vs. `foo`.
In the given context, “&” can be used as such, since it is followed by a space, but it is generally recommended to escape it as “&amp;” anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`&amp;` is better, because it is html encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the html entity although both will work in most browsers.

```
&amp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <meta name="description" content="text text &amp; text...">
```